# How to show popup window in Jquery on validation event of a Date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm stuck trying to find a good solution for my issue.
Can anyone tell me how to How to show popup window on validation event of a Date.I am using jQuery validation plug-in 1.6 for validation (jquery.validate.js). My scenario is that when a user select a date, I validate that date and show proper error message if not valid.If date is Invalid, I want a popup window for a password to make invalid date to valid.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any good solution for this.

This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $('#txtDate').rules("add", { required: true, restrictDate: true, messages: { required: "Please enter log date", restrictDate: "Check the selected date." } });
    ...
    $.validator.addMethod("restrictDate", function (value, element) { var activityDate = GetDate($('#txtDate').val(), formatOfDate); if (Date.parse(activityDate) > Date.parse(dt)) { return false; } else return true; }, "Date comparison error." );
    ...
    //Registering date picker
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, constrainInput: true });
```

```
...
....
```

)};

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far, please?

Comment: $('#txtDate').rules("add", { required: true, restrictDate: true, messages: { required: "Please enter log date", restrictDate: "Check the selected date." } });

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("restrictDate", function (value, element) {
                var activityDate = GetDate($('#txtDate').val(), formatOfDate);
                if (Date.parse(activityDate) > Date.parse(dt)) {
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            },
           "Date comparison error."
         );

Comment: //Registering date picker
            $('#txtDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                constrainInput: true
            });

Comment: Where is `.validate()` code?

Comment: @Sparky,validatorObject = $('#formMaster').validate({
                onsubmit: false
            });

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [dialog component of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)? You can show arbitrary modal dialogs (popups) with any messages you want.

Using the jQuery validate plugin, use the `invalidHandler` when calling validate like so:

```
$(".selector").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        // If there are any errors in your form, control reaches this function
        // First check if your date field was the source of the error
        if(validator.element('#datefield')){
            // If it was, show the dialog box you want.
            $('#yourdiv').html("<div> Any html message/content you want here</div>");
            $('#yourdiv').dialog();
        }
    }
 })
```

Comment: hi,thanks for reply.i dont want to show any error message in that popup.im showing the error message in a lebel next to datatime.

Comment: But you can use this to show the popup window if the Date is valid.

Comment: You can use this for doing that too. Change the html of the dialog to show any message/content you want.

Comment: my validation rule is like  $('#txtDate').rules("add", {
                required: true,                              
                restrictDate: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Please enter log date",              
                    restrictDate: "Check the selected date."
                }
            });How to do that ?

Comment: What are you using to do the validation? Is it a jQuery plugin? You might want to add that information to the question.

Comment: sorry for that.am using jQuery validation plug-in 1.6

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$('#dateId').valid()){
    $('#divId').html("Error message");
    $( "#divId" ).dialog();
}
```